# Time difference logic based on transfers in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an activity table where I have some data for a ticket activity. Columns are ticket number, created by and date and time. At first ticket will create in IVR or PinBased and then will transfer to an agent. Now I need to get the time difference between the IVR and the Agent only when the first created agent is IVR. If first agent is not IVR I need to exclude the timediff.

Lets say for Raj , the ticket created at 7/19/2019 12:40 Am by PinBased then went to IVR so we need exclude this tickets .

Lets say for Ramu the ticket created at 7/19/2019 04:40 Am by IVR then assigned to Ramu at 7/19/2019 04:40 ,So I need to show the timediff as 3600 secs.

If the ticket created by IVR then i need to get time difference between 2nd and 3rd rows of the time. This is fix.

PFA sample data.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want `DATEDIFF`.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a previous row comparison and need the `lag` function along with `datediff` to help.

In the below code I group the max  `[Date and Time]` per actor in `CreatedBy` in a derived table and run the above functions where the actor is not IVR.  I've put some test data into a temp table but you can adapt to your own data. To get your own columns you can `inner join` the derived table with alias `t` onto your original query:

```
    if object_id('tempdb..#temp') is not null
    drop table #temp;

create table #temp (
    TicketNo int,
    CreatedBy varchar(100),
    [Date and Time] datetime2(3),
    [Type] varchar(100),
    [Description] varchar (100)
)
insert into #temp (TicketNo,CreatedBy, [Date and Time],[Type],[Description])

values 
(1000, 'Agent1','2019-01-01 01:00:00.000','type3','desc3'),
(1000, 'IVR','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000','type2','desc2'),
(1000, 'IVR','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000','type1','desc1'),
(2000, 'Agent2','2019-01-01 07:00:00.000','type3','desc3'),
(2000, 'IVR','2019-01-01 05:00:00.000','type2','desc2'),
(2000, 'IVR','2019-01-01 05:00:00.000','type3','desc3');



select 
o.TicketNo,
o.CreatedBy,
o.[Date and Time],
o.[Type],
o.[Description],
lag(t.[Date and Time]) over (partition by t.TicketNo order by t.[Date and Time] asc)  as PreviousCreatedBy,
case when 
    t.CreatedBy <> 'IVR'
    then
        datediff(second
                    ,lag(t.[Date and Time]) over (partition by t.TicketNo order by t.[Date and Time] asc)
                    ,t.[Date and Time])
    else null
    end  as TimeDifference
from #temp as o
inner join (
    select
    TicketNo
    ,CreatedBy
    ,max([Date and Time]) as [Date and Time]
    from #temp
    group by TicketNo, CreatedBy
    ) as t
    on o.TicketNo = t.TicketNo
        and o.CreatedBy = t.CreatedBy
```

Comment: Below is my original query and getting error like this..   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.                                    
 select 
datediff(second,lag(act.time_stamp) over (partition by cr.ref_num order by act.time_stamp asc) ,act.time_stamp) as SecDiff
from act_log act with (Nolock)
INNER JOIN call_req cr with (nolock) on cr.persid = act.call_req_id

where cr.ref_num  = '14692654'
order by act.id asc

Comment: What data type and length is the column 'time_stamp' in the table 'act_log' please? Is it a varchar?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using **lag** function in sql

```
Select 
TicketNo,
CreatedBy,
`Date and Time`,
    Datediff(second,`Date and Time`,lag(`Date and Time`)
      Over (partition by TicketNo order by `Date and Time` asc)) as SecDiff
From Table
```

Comment: Below is my original query and getting error like this..   Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.                                    
 select 
datediff(second,lag(act.time_stamp) over (partition by cr.ref_num order by act.time_stamp asc) ,act.time_stamp) as SecDiff
from act_log act with (Nolock)
INNER JOIN call_req cr with (nolock) on cr.persid = act.call_req_id

where cr.ref_num  = '14692654'
order by act.id asc

Comment: convert the lag() to datetime value

Comment: Hey Anthony I have many rows for the same ticket.I only need time diff between 2nd and 3rd rows as from the third row contains the tranfer time from IVR to Agent.From your result I am getting all the rows time diff.Please suggest

Comment: It is difference between the transactions. It will help in times. Why do you only need for those two rows? It is a feature not a bug :)

Comment: Let's add a if else if you do not want for other rows

Comment: They Need the time diff between the ticket gets transferred from IVR to assignee agent only.

Comment: (case when type='assignee transfer' then <include the date diff part here> else null end) @vissubabu